# Cocos2D Menu Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to make a button from an image that takes the player from current scene (game scene) back to the menu scene, resetting the current scene (game scene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like This:

```
-(void)showBackBtnMenu
{
    CCSprite *backButtonNormal = [CCSprite         spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"btnBackNormal.png"]; //Make sure u already added this sprite sheet. Otherwise use sprite from file.
    CCSprite *backButtonSelected = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"btnBackSelected.png"];

    CCMenuItemSprite *backButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:backButtonNormal selectedSprite:backButtonSelected disabledSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(backBtnPress:)];

    backButton.position = ccp(63.0f, 34.0f);

 CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:backButton, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(0,0); 
    [self addChild:menu z:3]; //Make sure this z value is higher than ur background
}


-(void)backBtnPress:(id)sender
{
       [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[transition transitionWithDuration:duration scene:[MyMainMenu scene]]];
}
```

Comment: You may want to check if the button is ever added or if it is covered up by a higher z order object.